# AspectJ NoSuchMethodError with Spring

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have a spring web rest project (3.0.4) running with aspectJ (1.8.14) for logging.
I have a pointcut defined in all methods that are annotated with @Logging.

When I call a generic helloWorld controller annotated with @Logging. **AspectJ works fine.**

When I call the real controller annotated with @Logging, which also happens to call a lib jar method that is also annotated with @Logging. Unfortunally, during the inner method call the error below occurs.
How does it come that only the method inside the lib has such error?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
  logging.aop.LoggingAspect.ajc$inlineAccessFieldGet$logging_aop_LoggingAspect$logging_aop_LoggingAspect$pLogger()Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
service.impl.DAOClass.getMethod_aroundBody1$advice(DAOClass.java:101)
service.impl.DAOClass.getMethod(DAOClass.java:1)
```

**What I tried:** I checked jdk compiled versions, jar versions in maven dependencies, web.xml and aop.xml configuration and installing AJDT plugin for eclipse photon to debug. I tried to deploy in weblogic to see the class loader, but I was not able to, trying in tomcat i cannot see what is loaded or not.

P.S: please do not downgrade the question for lack of code, i would have to make a complete mock to avoid showing company code for now I am looking for people that worked with AOP with spring and has some idea what I am using based on this info plus the error stack. I can make a mock code later if nobody guess what is the cause until there.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. I do understand that it is difficult to create, especially if an application server like WebLogic is also involved and might mess with your class-loading. But still more information would be valuable if you are looking for help here: Please show your aspect, I want to see what it does. Please also schematically (pseudo code?) explain which class calls which class in which way. How are you weaving the code, via `-javaagent:/my/path/aspectweaver.jar`? Tell us as much as possible about your setup.

Comment: There is no -javaagent configuration even though there is a pom.xml in META-INF so I assume it is not using that xml and just some defaults from the pom dependency `<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId><artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>`. Sorry, I promise I will make code example that reproduces the error, probably a link to github due too much code.

Answer (score 0):

No SuchMethodError usually happens when runtime class path contains different version/both version of jar the library was  compile against. You should check the pom dependency against runtime class path. I bet it was promoted to newer version which is not backward compatible. How do you package your application, spring boot?

Comment: No spring boot =(, app is packaged with maven plugins. We also thought it could be that, we checked the code of the possible newer version it could be promoting and the old version, and the error doesn't justify it.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Web app sever? Which one? Executable jar? You can  check the root class path provided by your web app to find the competing library...